# insertAt and removeAt vector methods missing from cs4 but present in documentation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I seem to be having some trouble with the vector methods removeAt and insertAt, they are both present in the documentation for as3:

"https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#insertAt()"

And yet in adobe flash cs4 they are undefined and throw up errors. Does cs4 not have these methods or is the documentation poor?

Comment: **Runtime Versions**: Flash Player 19. I think CS4 is originally packed with Flash Player 10. Hence, the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: I never tried it with CS4, but in theory it is possible. You need to download any relevant AIR SDK (19 or later) then set up your CS4 IDE as following (probably): https://swfhead.wordpress.com/2009/09/18/using-air-sdk-1-5-2-in-flash-cs4/ (I googled it with **flash cs4 air sdk** so there could be more relevant links).

Comment: There's another option, if your project is not a regular FLA with assets and frame scripts, but script-only with external assets. In this case you can use AIR SDK to compile your project directly or via **FlashDevelop** or any other dedicated IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's an option other then upgrading to newest version of Flash Player and SDK. It is not a better option, not very elegant, yet simpler. Unless you are running some huge datasets, performance of the **VPlus.insertAt(...)** implementation is not an issue too.

Implementation:

```
package
{
    public class VPlus
    {
        static public function deleteAt(V:*, index:int):void
        {
            // The method cuts a portion of Vector and returns it.
            // We need just the "cut" part, yet it suffices.
            V.splice(index, 1);
        }

        static public function insertAt(V:*, index:int, element:*):void
        {
            // Fix for from-the-end-and-backwards indexing.
            if (index < 0)
            {
                index = V.length - index;
            }

            // Add one more element to the end of the given Vector.
            V.push(null);

            // Shift the Vector's elements from index and on.
            for (var i:int = V.length - 2; i >= index; i--)
            {
                V[i+1] = V[i];
            }

            // Put the new element to its designated place.
            V[index] = element;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// myVec.deleteAt(10);
VPlus.deleteAt(myVec, 10);

// myVec.insertAt(15, "Hello World!");
VPlus.insertAt(myVec, 15, "Hello World!");
```